# jQuery animate callbox into different positions

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a phone icon on my website, when you click on it, the icon slides to the right, revealing the phone number that was hidden off the width of the site. This is the code that I'm using for that:

```
$(".call-button").click(function(){
$(".call-button").animate({ 
    left: "+=225px",
}, 1000 );
});
```

The problem is that once the phone number is revealed, if you click the box again, it moves an additional 225px to the right. Is there a way to make it so that if the CSS left property is set to 0, then once the box is clicked it moves back to -225px?

Answer (score -1):

Try using toggle:

```
$(".call-button").toggle(
  function() {
    $(this).stop(true).animate({ left: "0" }, 1000 );
  }, 
  function() { 
    $(this).stop(true).animate({ left: "-225px" }, 1000 );
  }
);
```

​